# Reading multiple columns url cv file

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Does anyone here know what is wrong with my code? I am having trouble to slice the df dataset into a new dataset with two or more columns. The dataset is called US crime rate and I would like to create a new dateset called df1 with Rape and Murder column only. The iloc works without any issue but I would like to slice the data set using the title of column not the number of the column. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
url= 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GeekOnAcid/da022affd36310c96cd4/raw/9c2ac2b033979fcf14a8d9b2e3e390a4bcc6f0e3/us_nr_of_crimes_1960_2014.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df1 = df[['Rape', 'Murder']]
```

Comment: It seems like there is a space at end of each column name. `dataset[['Rape ', 'Murder ']]` this should work

Comment: yes... using `df1 = df[['Rape ', 'Murder ']]` will fix this issue

Comment: Thanks David for the smart look. The easy fix is to make an extra space but is there any way to remove the space from the dataset?

Comment: with `'String '.strip()`

Comment: `dataset.columns = pd.Series(dataset.columns).str.strip(" ")` This should do it

Comment: Thanks David. The problem is solved. Very helpful. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` method to remove space from the column names. Details of `rename` method can be [read in the official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```
import pandas as pd
url= 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GeekOnAcid/da022affd36310c96cd4/raw/9c2ac2b033979fcf14a8d9b2e3e390a4bcc6f0e3/us_nr_of_crimes_1960_2014.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip(), inplace=True)
print(df.columns)
df1 = df[['Rape', 'Murder']]
print(df1.head())
```

Output:

```
Index(['Year', 'Total', 'Violent', 'Property', 'Murder', 'Rape', 'Robbery',
       'Aggravated-Assault', 'Burglary', 'Larceny-Theft', 'Vehicle-Theft'],
      dtype='object')
   Rape  Murder
0   9.6     5.1
1   9.4     4.8
2   9.4     4.6
3   9.4     4.6
4  11.2     4.9
```